# Finding top dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have 3 dictionaries I've aggregated (cities, subcountries, countries)

I need a function that will give me the n top results from those dictionaries.

So far I have code that only gives me the top of each not top 3 or top n defined in my params.

```
def top_items(item_counts, n=3):
    d = collections.Counter(item_counts)
    d.most_common()
    for k, v in d.most_common(n):
        return (k, v)
```

I tried just d = Counter(item_counts) but it gives the error Counter is undefined. I also imported re and collections.

I'm trying to run

```
print('top cities:', top_items(cities))
print('top states:', top_items(subcountries))
print('top countries:', top_items(countries))
```

but get

```
top cities: ('', 665)
top states: ('', 552)
top countries: ('', 502)
```

Comment: Can you give input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement inside your for loop is causing your function to terminate during the loop's first iteration. If what you want to do is return the *n* most common items you can simply write

```
def top_items(items, n=3):
   counts = collections.Counter(items)
   return counts.most_common(n)
```

Comment: Thanks @joantan! One curious question. If I wanted to return just the keys not the values, its not occurring to me how to slice the list. ie your code gives : [(los angeles, 15), (denver, 10), (seattle, 5)], how would you return just the cities, not the counts. Thanks!

Comment: You could either convert it to a dict and then retrieve the dict's keys or use a list comprehension / map.
so `dict(counts.most_common(n)).keys()` or `[t[0] for t in counts.most_common(n)]`

Comment: This will also work: `next(zip(*counts.most_common(n)))`